# OpenCV Motion Tracking Using Feature Detector

Tags: opencv, feature-detection, motion-detection

I was wondering If I can detect motion more reliably by using Feature Detectors (like SURF, ORB, etc...)... Will it work for human beings in a video stream?

Comment: Tracking people is always difficult and really dependent on conditions. Can you give any more specifics on your particular application?

Comment: I'll have a fixed camera in the ceilling. Getting a nearly top-down view... I have to track people in a store. So there may be some occlusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SIFT flow](http://people.csail.mit.edu/celiu/ECCV2008/) may give you some ideas.

Comment: Is it implemented in OpenCV?

Comment: Yeah I'm pretty sure it isn't as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've done a project in OpenCV which may be useful to you. 
You can find it [here](http://geekbrothers.org/index.php/categories/computer/14-motion-detector)

Comment: It would be useful to include the salient features of your code, preferably with code snippets, in your answer.